NASDAQ Python SDK Client - How to resolve Market Open/Close Data Delay?
I am using the NASDAQ Python SDK client to consume market data for the NLSUTP topic. The data is fetched using the NCDSClient and processed in real-time. I send the data received from the consumer via WebSocket. During normal market hours, I get multiple responses from WebSocket within 1 second, which works as expected. However, during market opening and closing timestamps, I experience significant delays in receiving messages. These delays are sometimes more than 15 seconds, and occasionally up to a few minutes, which is problematic for my real-time application.
Code Snippet
Below is the relevant portion of my code:
def init_nasdaq_kafka_connection(topic):  
    security_cfg = {  
        "oauth.token.endpoint.uri": os.getenv("NASDAQ_KAFKA_ENDPOINT"),  
        "oauth.client.id": os.getenv("NASDAQ_KAFKA_CLIENT_ID"),  
        "oauth.client.secret": os.getenv("NASDAQ_KAFKA_CLIENT_SECRET"),  
    }  
    kafka_cfg = {  
        "bootstrap.servers": os.getenv("NASDAQ_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_URL"),  
        "auto.offset.reset": "latest",  
        "socket.keepalive.enable": True,  
    }  

    ncds_client = NCDSClient(security_cfg, kafka_cfg)  
    consumer = ncds_client.ncds_kafka_consumer(topic)  
    logger.info(f"Success to connect NASDAQ Kafka server for topic {topic}.")  
    return consumer  

# Usage  
consumer = init_nasdaq_kafka_connection("NLSUTP")  

while True:  
    messages = consumer.consume(num_messages=1000000, timeout=0.25)  
    if messages:  
        response = makeRespFromKafkaMessages(messages)  
        # Sending response via WebSocket  

I wrote a script with connect to the websocket and save data in a format {current_datetime}_{number_of_messages}.json
During normal hours I received data like this where you can see I get multiple records in 1 second:
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-52-00-256_13.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-52-00-754_12.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-52-01-458_45.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-52-01-956_26.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-52-02-556_48.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-52-03-310_45.json

But during market close I get this:
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-54-48-756_405.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-54-56-198_500.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-55-05-019_1033.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-55-21-788_2057.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-55-42-214_1318.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-56-00-091_1324.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-56-15-703_1200.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-56-32-602_1120.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-56-46-802_1149.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-57-00-099_940.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-57-13-380_875.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-57-24-969_936.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-57-36-150_789.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-57-49-312_1202.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-58-03-939_1068.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-58-22-238_1290.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-58-43-967_1553.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-59-12-348_1734.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_15-59-42-903_2091.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_16-00-11-254_2853.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_16-01-17-148_5911.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_16-01-49-192_2566.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_16-02-05-338_5035.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_16-02-27-056_2343.json
Data saved to ./websocket_data/2024-12-31_16-02-39-615_36.json

In the file 2024-12-31_16-02-27-056_2343.json the timestamp of last
message is 2024-12-31 16:00:01.072991  which shows we got the data after 2:26 minutes.
Observations

During normal market hours, the WebSocket receives multiple responses within 1 second, which works as expected.
During market opening and closing timestamps:

The data flow is delayed significantly.
Delays range from 15 seconds to a few minutes.
The WebSocket responses also experience delays during this period.



Expected Behavior
The data should have minimal delay, even during the high-activity periods of market opening and closing. The WebSocket should receive multiple responses within 1 second, similar to normal market hours.
Questions

Is this delay expected behavior for the NASDAQ Python SDK client during market open/close times?
Are there any configuration options or optimizations to reduce these delays?
Could this issue be related to server-side throttling, Kafka settings, or network latency?

Environment Details

NASDAQ Python SDK version: Latest
Python version: 3.10.6
OS: Windows 10


Since it happens at repeated-predictable times I would wager the issue is the websocket server that you're connecting with. Even if it's supposed to have high-availability, they may have throttling or other conditions in place to ensure that market open and close operate as needed. I would probably raise this as an issue on the SDK's github page (if it has one) to see if they know more info

already raised one https://github.com/Nasdaq/NasdaqCloudDataService-SDK-Python/issues/56
